# Enable S3 ACL access for CloudFront logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

What I try to do is to enable Standard Logging for a CloudFront distribution, via AWS console, as in the picture below:

[image: AWS Console]

I have set the following S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::931426637260:user/relu"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[...]"
        }
    ]
}
```

"Block all public access" is Off.

Though, I keep getting this error:

> The S3 bucket that you specified for CloudFront logs does not enable
> ACL access: [...].s3.amazonaws.com

I get this error even if I try to enable logging as the root user.

Does anybody have any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems I had to enable ACL here:

[image]

Answer (score 24):

[Starting in April 2023, you will need to enable S3 access control lists (ACLs) for new S3 buckets being used for CloudFront standard logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#AccessLogsBucketAndFileOwnership%5D):

(screenshot)
[image: message on aws]

(even though at the same time [AWS tells you that it's not recommended to enable ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) )

> A majority of modern use cases in S3 no longer require the use of ACLs, and we recommend that you keep ACLs disabled

So as far as I have been able to determine, there is no way to adhere to the second message/recommendation (disable ACLs), while getting your CloudFront logs in your bucket.

If you're using the UI, see [user3429660's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70645554/1207489).

In case someone is looking how to do this in CloudFormation:

```yaml
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties: 
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerPreferred
      [....]
```

(alternatively use `ObjectOwnership: ObjectWriter`)

That's all that's needed; even when using CloudFormation, the CloudFront Logger will automatically add itself to the ACLs (as long as they are enabled).

Comment: Thanks for posting this updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

The reason it isn't working is that the S3 Object Ownership prevents CloudFront from delivering log files to the bucket. The accepted answer is correct, however, it took me a second to get to that setting.

To get to the setting

```
S3 -> Buckets -> Your_bucket_name -> Permissions -> Object Ownership
```

The object ownership setting will be a little bit down the page. Hopefully, this helps someone! I'm happy to provide more detail if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

For Terraform users:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id

  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this line from the docs covers your findings:

> That setting disables ACLs for the bucket and the objects in it, which prevents CloudFront from delivering log files to the bucket.

ie. ACLs are needed
relevant docs are here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html

Answer (score 3):

**Check that you're not trying to send CloudFront logs to an S3 bucket in an unsupported region.**

Yep - that's right, CloudFront doesn't support writing logs to S3 buckets in all regions. This is probably a less common problem, but it snagged me up.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#access-logs-choosing-s3-bucket

> **Important**
>
> Don't choose an Amazon S3 bucket in any of the following Regions, because CloudFront doesn't deliver standard logs to buckets in these Regions:
>
> ```
> - Africa (Cape Town)
> - Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)
> - Asia Pacific (Hyderabad)
> - Asia Pacific (Jakarta)
> - Asia Pacific (Melbourne)
> - Europe (Milan)
> - Europe (Spain)
> - Europe (Zurich)
> - Middle East (Bahrain)
> - Middle East (UAE)
> ```

For the record, the error I was getting from CloudFormation was:

> Resource handler returned message: "Access denied for operation 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution: You don't have permission to access the S3 bucket for CloudFront logs: xxxxx.s3.ap-southeast-4.amazonaws.com If you're using IAM, you need s3:GetBucketAcl and s3:PutBucketAcl permissions to create a distribution or to update log settings for an existing distribution. In addition, the S3 ACL for the bucket must grant you FULL_CONTROL. (Service: CloudFront, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 82xex74x-x184-472h-aekl-944276356rfe)'." (RequestToken: aekd4b6e-45ha-489a-013e-6203kl194c21, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)

Comment: This caught me out too. Thanks for the post. Super helpful.

Comment: This was the issue for me. AWS Console was not really helpful as pointint rather to a permission issue!